# NGINX Removes my Favicon (works fine through mysite.com:3000)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

When I visit my site directly through "mysite.com:3000", it correctly displays my favicon.

When I visit through NGINX forwarding 80 to 3000 - "mysite.com", it does not display my favicon, despite being able to see it correctly in the source, and clicking the favicon in the source works fine.

All other aspects of the site render correctly, just the favicon is missing (not a 400 error, it is not finding it in the source, even though I can see it via "View Page Source".

Here is the start of the head section on my page -

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Here is the info for "curl -i http:mysite.com/favicon.ico"

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 18:47:30 GMT
Content-Type: image/x-icon
Content-Length: 318
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 02:30:49 GMT
ETag: W/"13e-1588f057585"
Vary: Accept-Encoding

(( ▒▒▒?    ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒_wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwqwwwwwwqwwwwwwqwwwwwwqwwwwwwwwwww    w!wwwwwvQgwwww11wwwwAgxwwwvwwAgww1wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

Any ideas?

I originally set up NGINX yesterday with these instructions from Digital Ocean (I did not set up the end about using SSL) - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

If it helps at all, I am running a NodeJS app at the 3000 port, Ubuntu 16.04 x 64.

Thanks!

Comment: Show output of `curl -I http://<site>/<favicon>` and `<head>` of containing page at least, please?

Comment: @Ryan Updated above, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: `curl -I http://<site>/favicon.ico`, then?

Comment: @Ryan added, sorry missed that part.

Comment: If you remove proxying from Nginx and just serve the HTML and favicon statically, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example and make sure You've configured it something alike:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name _;

    index index.html index.htm;

    # this serves for any static file that has extension from regular expression
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|mp3|xml)$ {
        root /home/app/public;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location / {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        # my node app listens on 8000
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look. I originally set up NGINX via these instructions on Digital Ocean (minus the section at the end about adding SSL). Your file is more detailed than the one they had me create - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @tkwitten Yes, I know this tutorial. My sample is copy of working file: https://bitbucket.org/num8er/nix/src/1ca484af35dd0e59f495d6a207858232b080c242/vhost.conf?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default "extra version" of the config from the tutorial. Very long time ago had same question. (: